# Which unix / linux flavor should I learn looking at job opportunities in future?

Tags: linux, centos

I am a Computer Engineer and I want to start exploring the Unix & Linux environment.

Which flavor of Unix and also Linux should I learn looking at a job opportunity in these two fields in future?

Please suggest me, I am really looking forward to have a future in Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You should explore a few distributions with at least the two main package types :

- A rpm-based (like RHEL, fedora, ...)
- A deb-base (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint,...)

And the two main init :

- systemd (which is on pretty much every last versions of the main distributions)
- sysV, the legacy init you can still find on Debian 7 "Wheezy" , or RHEL 6

You should also take a look at a BSD (freeBSD ?).

Hope I helped !

Comment: RHEL 6 uses upstart, not sysV. You need to go back to RHEL 5 for sysV.